# Combine two queries into one to cherry pick related columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, subquery

I have two tables one called customer_sales and another distinct_customers.

This query returns the total number of sales per d_id and customer number (but does not have the customer name)

```
select cs.d_id, cs.customer_number, cs.total_sales from cs_sales cs where cs.d_id = 'A00007';
```

This query returns the customer information (including name) from the d_id

```
select  dc.c_name, dc.c_number, dc.d_name from dcust dc where d_id ='A00007';
```

I want to combine both queries so that I can get something like this

```
|-------|--------|-----------|-------------|
|d_id   | c_name |   d_name  | total_sales |
|-------|--------|-----------|-------------|
```

whats the best way to do this?
ive tried different ways and I keep on getting duplicate information back.

Distinct_customers sample data

[image]

customer_sales sample data

[image]

Comment: It is better if you will show what you've tried and which result you got

Comment: @DmitryReutov I tried something better similar to the below answer but it returns duplicate records with c_name and d_name duplicated

Comment: Do the queries in your question return only 1 row each?

Comment: @forpas I added some sample data.  This is driving me insane lol

Comment: So there are multiple rows in each table for d_id ='A00007', which you did not clarify in your question. And what is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas  Yes, thats correct.  A dealer has customers with assigned customers numbers. But, another dealer could have the same customer number for that dealer.  So the unique identifiers is d_id and c_number per dealer.

Comment: @forpas I want to be able to get the dealer_name, the c_name and their total sales per customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join on `customer_number` too:

```
SELECT cs.d_id, dc.c_name, dc.d_name, cs.total_sales
FROM cs_sales cs INNER JOIN dcust dc
ON cs.d_id = dc.d_id AND dc.customer_number = cs.customer
WHERE cs.d_id ='A00007'
```

Comment: BOOM! Your a Genius.  Thats it.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to join the tables:

```
select cs.d_id, dc.c_name, dc.d_name, cs.total_sales
from dcust d inner join cs_sales cs 
on d.d_id = cs.d_id
where d_id = 'A00007'
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this but this returns duplicate results. 

`A00007 Deandra Craft A00007 Ibex Dealer 52425
A00007 Deandra Craft A00007 Ibex Dealer 53790
A00007 Deandra Craft A00007 Ibex Dealer 5927
A00007 Deandra Craft A00007 Ibex Dealer 23069
A00007 Deandra Craft A00007 Ibex Dealer 56121
`

Answer (score 0):

The below code should do the job:

```
SELECT cs.d_id, dc.c_name, dc.d_name, SUM(cs.total_sales)
FROM cs_sales cs
LEFT JOIN dcust dc
ON cs.d_id=dc.d_id
GROUP BY cs.d_id, dc.c_name, dc.d_name
```

Comment: This is ALMOST exactly what I need but instead of returning the sum, how can I get it to return each sale per row?

`A00007 Neomi Ashbaug A00007 Ibex Dealer 1695348
A00007 Oswaldo Klein A00007 Ibex Dealer 1695348
A00007 Rachele Nazar A00007 Ibex Dealer 3390696
A00007 Raisa Virgen  A00007 Ibex Dealer 1695348
A00007 Reynalda Jury A00007 Ibex Dealer 1695348
A00007 Rolando Kibbe A00007 Ibex Dealer 1695348
`

Comment: doesn't it give then the duplicate results ? (as you mentioned in the comment of @thiagotrss )   please explain on what field you expect to deduplicate and on which to group

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that you have the dealer id in both tables.  Based on the naming, I suspect that you want to join only on the customer and not on the dealer:

```
SELECT cs.d_id, c.c_name, c.d_name, cs.total_sales
FROM cs_sales cs INNER JOIN
     dcust c
     USING (c.customer_number) 
WHERE cs.d_id = 'A00007';
```

I interpret `cs.d_id` as something like "the dealership where the customer signed up".  I don't see why it would have to be the same as where the actual sale is made.  So, if you want the *sales* at a given dealer, use the dealer information from `cs_sales`.

If the column is redundant, then you should fix your data model so the column is not repeated across two tables.